# Cocoapods update generated Errors with JSONModel

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods, jsonmodel

Just updated my cocoapods gem.

Changed podfile as described in the elegant solution.

Short example of my podfile:

```
    platform :ios, '8.4'

use_frameworks!

def pods
    # visual
    pod 'ColorArt'
    # core
    pod 'JSONModel'
end

target 'myTargetOne' do
    pods
end

target 'myTargetTwo' do
    pods
end
```

But this resulted in lots of errors:

- Property Has a Previous Declaration
- Redefinition Cocoapods

[image]

EDIT: 
I discovered that XCode was not recognising any header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tries I discovered that Deleting Derived Data at Xcode solved the problem:

At Xcode 7.2.1 you can do the following:

⌘⌥⇧K

Which is Command + Option + Shift + K

Comment: I've faced out with similar problem after I turned to `use_frameworks!` in my project's Podfile. The solution was to substitute imports like `#import "JSONModel.h"` with `#import <JSONModel/JSONModel.h>` or `@import JSONModel;`